# sort data coming from get api in angular 8

Tags: angular

I am getting a list of products from api. I want to sort product as per our need as shown in below code

*my component.html*

```html
<select id="sort-by" (change)="sort($event)">
  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Sort By</option>
  <option value="Name">Product list A-Z</option>
  <option value="Name1">Product list Z-A</option>
  <option value="Date">Date</option>
  <option value="Low">Show Low to High Price</option>
  <option value="High">Show High to Low Price</option>
</select>
```

I am able to sort products based on product price from low to high and high to low but i am not able to sort data from A-Z, Z-A, Date

*my component.ts file*

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.productService.getProductList().subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log(res.payload);
      this.ProdData = res.payload;
    });
  }

  sort(event: any) {
    switch (event.target.value) {
      case "Low": {
        this.ProdData = this.ProdData.sort(
          (low, high) => low.Price - high.Price
        );
        break;
      }

      case "High": {
        this.ProdData = this.ProdData.sort(
          (low, high) => high.Price - low.Price
        );
        break;
      }

      case "Name": {
        this.ProdData.sort(function (a, b) {
          if (a.Name < b.Name) {
            return 1;
          }
          if (a.Name > b.Name) {
            return -1;
          }
          console.log(a.Name);
        });
      }
      case "Name1": {
        this.ProdData.reverse();
      }
      case "Date": {
        this.ProdData.sort(function (c, d) {
          return c.UpdatedAt - d.UpdatedAt;
        });
      }

      default: {
        this.ProdData = this.ProdData.sort(
          (low, high) => low.Price - high.Price
        );
        break;
      }
    }
    return this.ProdData;
  }
```

my api response is like

```
     Id: 2
     Name: "cvcb1"
     Price: "20"
     Description: "bgfhjgj"
     CamparePrice: "78"
     SkuNumber: "568669"
     Quantity: "1"
     UpdatedAt: "2020-04-23T11:59:47.000Z"
```

Comment: you can use `toLowercae()` and `trim()` method, and then pass it to sort order. for date transform date to `toISODateString()` that would be useful for comparision

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ezjpz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts look at this link.. is it working for you?

Comment: thanks @GaurangDhorda it really works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Demo in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ezjpz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
export interface pData{
  Id: number;
  Name: string;
  Price: String;
  Description: string;
  CamparePrice: string;
  SkuNumber: string;
  Quantity: string;
  UpdatedAt: string;
}
```

sorting order is as below..

```
sort(order){
    switch (order.target.value) {
      case "Low" : {
          this.productList = this.productList.sort(
              (low: pData, high: pData) => +low.Price - +high.Price
            );
        break;          
      }
      case "High": {
        this.productList = this.productList.sort(
          (low, high) => +high.Price - +low.Price
        );
       break;
     }
      case "Name1": {
        this.productList = this.productList.sort(
          (low, high) => high.Name.toLowerCase().trim() >  low.Name.trim().toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1
        );
        break;
      }
      case "Name": {
        this.productList = this.productList.sort(
          (low, high) => high.Name.toLowerCase().trim() <  low.Name.trim().toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1
        );
        break;
      }

      case "Date" : {
        this.productList = this.productList.sort((low, high) => high.UpdatedAt.trim().toLowerCase() < low.UpdatedAt.trim().toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1)
      }
    }
}
```

TemplateFile is..

```
<select id="sort-by" (change)="sort($event)">
      <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Sort By</option>
      <option value="Name">Product list A-Z</option>
      <option value="Name1">Product list Z-A</option>
      <option value="Date">Date</option>
      <option value="Low">Show Low to High Price</option>
      <option value="High">Show High to Low Price</option>
</select>
<hr>
<pre>
 {{productList |json}}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lodash to sort the name

```
import {orderBy} from 'lodash';
case "Name": {
this.ProdData = orderBy(this.ProdData, ['Name'],['asc']);
}
case "Name1": {
this.ProdData = orderBy(this.ProdData, ['Name'],['desc']);
}
```